# $conn->prepare returns false, can't find error

Tags: php, mysql

following PHP Command is returning false:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Kartennummer, Name, Typ, Farbe, Seltenheit, Edition, PreisInEuro, EinkaufspreisInEuro 
FROM karten 
WHERE (Typ LIKE ? AND Farbe LIKE ? AND Seltenheit LIKE ? AND Edition LIKE ?) 
ORDER BY PreisInEuro ?, EinkaufspreisInEuro ?, Name ?");
```

I can't find any error though, when I echo the statement before I get the following query for mysql:

```
SELECT Kartennummer, Name, Typ, Farbe, Seltenheit, Edition, PreisInEuro, EinkaufspreisInEuro 
FROM karten 
WHERE (Typ LIKE "%" AND Farbe LIKE "%" AND Seltenheit LIKE "%" AND Edition LIKE "%")
ORDER BY PreisInEuro ASC, EinkaufspreisInEuro ASC, Name ASC
```

When I query this directly to MySQL it does its job correctly and doesnt return any error. It only doesn't work in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I know the issue now.
It's seems that I cannot use the ? sign for ASC or DESC.